# Add swiper to hugo

Tags: javascript, css, slider, swiper.js, hugo

I would like to add swiper to make a slider to my test project, tha is based on hugo framework.
Unfortunately, it doesn;t work correctly.
Here is my github projects:
https://github.com/bullet03/carousel_site

What I've done:

1. Created a structure in layouts/_default/baseof.html, where i put partials/head.html and partials/header.html
2. in partials/head.html i added css styles for swiper and css for my code

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>
```

3. in partials/header.html i inserted partials/carousel.html
4. in partials/carousel.html i added html structure, at the end added js scripts for swiper

```html
<!-- Swiper JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Swiper -->
<script>
  var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {});
</script>
```

My css do not load, there is no mistake, it's just like there is no swiper and styles at all. Could you kindly, point out, how to fix it?

Comment: When you say CSS does not load - did you check your chrome/firefox inspector? Or do you mean, you don't see any CSS? Additionally, when you create a swiper with Swiper JS, there is required HTML, which I do not see in your post - did you add the needed HTML?

Comment: Not loading CSS is almost always a problem with the reference to the CSS file. You might have a mismatch in the path/link.

Answer (score 0):

When I cloned your repo and tried to display the page, it cannot be displayed because there is no `single.html` file in your `layouts/_default` directory. This file is used by Hugo to render [single pages](https://gohugo.io/templates/single-page-templates/) like your `a.md` is (it's not a [home page](https://gohugo.io/templates/homepage/) nor a [list page](https://gohugo.io/templates/lists/)).

Create a `layouts/_default/single.html` and put this content into it:

```
{{ define "main" }}
    <!-- 
        Place the content for single pages here, it will be rendered
        in a place where you'll add {{ block "main" . }}{{ end }}.
        Adding the block to your baseof.html is not necessary to
        achieve what you want to achieve (display the swiper).
    -->
{{ end }}
```

You don't need to add any content there unless you want to, just make sure the file exists and a block is defined inside of it.

For more information, see [template lookup order](https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/).